# nested stacks in AWS CloudFormation are not changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have more than 20 different services in AWS which are stacks defined in one main file (there are reference to template in .json), so these stacks are nested. Update of this stack is triggered by Codepipeline which is well configured with Github and production site. My problem is with during updating CF script because only main level resources are updated, unfortunately, I cannot see any changes which are linked with nested stacks. Why?

Comment: Do you mean you don't see anything in the change set?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I see still 16 changes but every time when I try to update stack. Why updating doesn't work properly in this case?

Comment: Nested stacks always show that they are updating, regardless of whether there are changes to be made.